# How make window.history.go(-1) from Blazor c# code?

Tags: blazor

How make window.history.go(-1) from c# code on Blazor?

I tried to use JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync

```
JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync< string >( "history.go", new[] {-1} );
JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync< string >( "top.history.go", new[] {-1} );
JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync< string >( "window.history.go", new[] {-1} );
JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync< string >( "window.top.history.go", new[] {-1} );
```

but I get the error: go called on an object that does not implement interface History.

But it work from cshtml:

```
<button id="BtnBack" type="button" onclick="window.history.go(-1)" class="btn btn-default">Back</button>
```

Comment: Do you get the same error for the four calls to InvokeAsync ?

Answer (score 7):

Not sure the details, but I believe to do interop like this, you need to be a bit more explicit about it.  So if you put this script in your `index.html` (not where I'd necessarily recommend you put it in production):

```
<script>
    window.test = {
        historyGo(value) {
            window.history.go(value);
        }
    };
</script>
```

Then put this code in your Blazor page:

```
<button type="button" onclick="@OnClick">Go Back</button>
```

With an event handler like this:

```
private void OnClick()
{
    JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<object>("test.historyGo", -1);
}
```

Everything works as you'd expect.  I tried the approach you took (without an explicit interop layer in your own JS) and likewise saw it did not work.  But this seems a reasonable workaround to me.  Would be interested in an elaboration for why *this* works and *your* code does not, but hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: In newer versios is: JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("test.historyGo", -1);

Answer (score 4):

This can be done without JavaScript.

Inject the JSRuntime into your component/page:

```
@inject IJSRuntime _jsRuntime
```

Invoke `history.go(-1)` directly:

```
_jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("history.go", -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

//-- Inject the JSRuntime into your component/page and call task
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

```
private async Task BackToPreviousPage()
{
    await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("history.back");  
}
```